# Why does VSCode not recognize the packages I use, but I am still able to run my application? (Dotnet, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

## Packages not recognized by VSCode

### The problem

I add a package to my project using `dotnet add package <PACKAGE_NAME>` and successfully adds that package to my project.
But when I try to use some methods and classes from that package, IntelliSense does not seem to have any reference to it and marks it with the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

I get the following error in the C# logs:

> [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Failure while loading c:\Users\phjes\Documents\Chirp\src\Chirp.Infrastructure\Chirp.Infrastructure.csproj: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers, version 7.0.11 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions.

The weird thing is that I am still able to run and build my project with no errors. Using `dotnet run` and `dotnet build`.

[Errors in the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6DUe.png)

### What I have tried

I have tried the following:

- Restoring packages using `dotnet restore`.
- Clearing nuget using:

  - `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`
  - `dotnet nuget locals global-packages --clear`
  - `dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear`
- Resetting dotnet language servers using `.net: Restart Language Server`  in VSCode.

None of this have worked, it still does not recognize any of the packages added.